# Source code of default Android 4 Apps (Clock Alarm Timer)

Tags: android

I can't find sources of android native apps for Android 4. I know about git hub repo but I have found only Alarm Clock app for Android 2. Please give me a link to source code of Clock app for Android 4. 
I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what "Clock app for Android 4" means. There are two "clock" apps in [the AOSP set of Git repositories](https://android.googlesource.com/), in terms of the project name having "clock" in it. [DeskClock](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/) is tagged for Android 4.x, while [AlarmClock](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/AlarmClock/) is not.

Comment: Is it possible to use this Clock for user made applications. These UI elements are not available.

Comment: @Ranjith: The AOSP apps generally are not designed to be built as SDK apps. You are welcome to copy code from them subject to their license terms and attempt to modify them for your use.